# Refactor multiple useEffects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I need to fetch multiple items (about 6)with different ID's passed via props, names are made up, f.e. `headerId, bodyId, footerId`.

I made an useEffect for each one:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getHeader = async () => {
        const header = await api.fetch(props.headerId);
        setHeader(header);
    }
    getHeader();
}, [props.headerId])
```

What I don't like is that now I have same `useEffect`s just with different `prop`, could I somehow merge all of them or this is the way I should do it.

Comment: do you expect the props to change or do you need to only fetch this once on initial mount?

Comment: It seems similar to the question I had y-day, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100887/redundant-piece-of-code-using-react-hooks/

Answer (score 1):

Passing multiple properties into array within `useEffect`, like:

```
}, [props.headerId, props.bodyId]);
```

will call the function if even one of the passed properties have changed. I believe you don't really want to call every async request to API (for new header, new body and so on) even if only one prop has changed.

Using multiple `useEffect` allows you to call only that particular request, that it's prop has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a higher order function that can be called with the state setter function and the prop name, that gets passed to `useEffect`:

```
const setAPIState = () => (prop, setter) => {
  api.fetch(props).then(setter);
};
```

```
// Then replace your original code with
const propsAndSetters = [
  [props.headerId, setHeader],
  [props.bodyId, setBody],
  // ...
];
for (const [prop, setter] of propsAndSetters) {
  useEffect(setAPIState(prop, setter), prop);
}
```

It's still somewhat repetitive, but since you want separate API calls for each different `prop`, you need a different `useEffect` for each one.